# Insert comma before last three digits of a mysql_fetch_array result?

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

is it at all possible to do this?
for instance if i had

```
$row['price']
```

and the value of this was 15000
I would like it to show as 15,000 but I dont have a clue about how to go about this?
thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the value 15000 without comma in your database???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$row['price'] = 15000;
echo substr($row['price'], 0, -3) . ',' . substr($row['price'], -3);

echo substr($row['price'], 0, -3); // == 15
echo substr($row['price'], -3); // == 000
```

The 0 is the start position of the string. The -15 is the negative end position of the string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: thanks that worked, can you explain it to me? i.e what the 0 does here:
substr($row['price'], 0, -3)
i can guess the minus 3 is the comma placement..

Comment: so 0, -3 = 0 start -3 from the end
then the second one with just -3 is ONLY saying the amount from the end? (being -3).

Comment: Yes that's right. Look at the PHP manual, there are many examples.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to FORMAT your data? How about using the `FORMAT` function?

```
FORMAT(X,D)

Formats the number X to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to D decimal places, and returns the result as a string. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part. D should be a constant value.

mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

**EDIT**: Sample query

As opposed to the SELECT * people use (too often), slightly modify your queries.

```
SELECT id, fullName, position, FORMAT(pay, 0) as pay 
FROM Employees WHERE lastName = 'Rubble';
```

Comment: to be honest i dont understand how i do that for the one result as the others are not numbers nor need formatting.

Comment: @Bob: Does the sample query make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

From PHP, you can use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$formatted = number_format($row['price']);
```

This will add a comma between every group of thousands. If you also want to format your price with a dot and two decimal places, use this:

```
$formatted = number_format($row['price'], 2);
```

Comment: The formatted value is stored in `$formatted`. Did you try `echo $formatted;` to check the output?

Comment: What is the price coming into the function? Is it > 1000? Also, since it's a price, you'll probably want the decimals too, right? then you have to use `number_format($row['price'], 2)` for 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do the formatting in MySQL then you can use the `FORMAT()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format